# How to combile two .so libs

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

I have two libs: libmy1.so and libmy2.so. libmy1.so is small and need the support of libmy2.so, which have a very large size. However, libmy1.so only need several function from libmy2.so. Is there any way I can use to link there function into libmy1.so, so that libmy1.so can be used without libmy2.so?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a static version of my2 you can link them and libmy1.so will contain what it needs from libmy2.a removing the need to include both libs.

Take a look at this page for some pointers: [Examples of .so and .a libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use dlopen/dlsym for the functions that require libmy2.so.

Unfortunately it is not possible to check for the presence of libmy2.so on start-up. So when the function that requires libmy2.so is called the first time libmy1.so must load libmy2.so.

If libmy2.so is not present or cannot be loaded you'll have to do some error reaction.